# Unable to create/write to a file on Android Phonegap

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I am trying to create a file on Android using:

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

function onDeviceReady() {
    window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, gotFS, fail);
}

function gotFS(fileSystem) {
    fileSystem.root.getFile("example.txt", {
        create: true
    }, gotFileEntry, fail);
}

function gotFileEntry(fileEntry) {
    fileEntry.createWriter(gotFileWriter, fail);
}

function gotFileWriter(writer) {
    writer.onwriteend = function(evt) {
        console.log("contents of file now 'some sample text'");
        writer.truncate(11);
        writer.onwriteend = function(evt) {
            console.log("contents of file now 'some sample'");
            writer.seek(4);
            writer.write(" different text");
            writer.onwriteend = function(evt) {
                console.log("contents of file now 'some different text'");
            }
        };
    };
    writer.write("some sample text");
}

function fail(error) {
    console.log(error.code);
}
```

This code works fine on iOS and I can see the file getting created inside Documents folder. However on Android I do not see any file.

I have added all the plugins. Also I have taken the following steps in order

1. Add plugins
   cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.file
   cordova plugin add org.apache.file-transfer
2. Compile and build android from within my app
   cordova compile android
   cordova build android

Also my config file has following entries:

```
<name>Hello Cordova</name>

<description>
    A sample Apache Cordova application that responds to the deviceready event.
</description>



<access origin="*"/>


<content src="index.html" />

<!-- Preferences for iOS -->
<preference name="AllowInlineMediaPlayback" value="false" />
<preference name="AutoHideSplashScreen" value="true" />
<preference name="BackupWebStorage" value="cloud" />
<preference name="DisallowOverscroll" value="false" />
<preference name="EnableLocation" value="false" /><!-- DEPRECATED -->
<preference name="EnableViewportScale" value="false" />
<preference name="FadeSplashScreen" value="true" />
<preference name="FadeSplashScreenDuration" value=".25" />
<preference name="HideKeyboardFormAccessoryBar" value="false" />
<preference name="KeyboardDisplayRequiresUserAction" value="true" />
<preference name="KeyboardShrinksView" value="false" />
<preference name="MediaPlaybackRequiresUserAction" value="false" />
<preference name="ShowSplashScreenSpinner" value="true" />
<preference name="SuppressesIncrementalRendering" value="false" />
<preference name="TopActivityIndicator" value="gray" />
<preference name="iosPersistentFileLocation" value="Library" />


<feature name="Geolocation">
  <param name="ios-package" value="CDVLocation"/>
</feature>
<feature name="Device">
  <param name="ios-package" value="CDVDevice"/>
</feature>
<feature name="Accelerometer">
  <param name="ios-package" value="CDVAccelerometer"/>
</feature>
<feature name="Compass">
  <param name="ios-package" value="CDVLocation"/>
</feature>
<feature name="Media">
  <param name="ios-package" value="CDVSound"/>
</feature>
<feature name="Camera">
  <param name="ios-package" value="CDVCamera"/>
</feature>
<feature name="Contacts">
  <param name="ios-package" value="CDVContacts"/>
</feature>
<feature name="File">
  <param name="ios-package"  value="CDVFile"/>
</feature>
<feature name="NetworkStatus">
  <param name="ios-package" value="CDVConnection"/>
</feature>
<feature name="Notification">
  <param name="ios-package" value="CDVNotification"/>
</feature>
<feature name="FileTransfer">
  <param name="ios-package" value="CDVFileTransfer"/>
</feature>
<feature name="Capture">
  <param name="ios-package" value="CDVCapture"/>
</feature>
<feature name="Battery">
  <param name="ios-package" value="CDVBattery"/>
</feature>
<feature name="SplashScreen">
  <param name="ios-package" value="CDVSplashScreen"/>
</feature>
<feature name="Echo">
  <param name="ios-package" value="CDVEcho"/>
</feature>
<feature name="Globalization">
  <param name="ios-package" value="CDVGlobalization"/>
</feature>
<feature name="InAppBrowser">
  <param name="ios-package" value="CDVInAppBrowser"/>
</feature>
<feature name="Logger">
  <param name="ios-package" value="CDVLogger"/>
</feature>
<feature name="LocalStorage">
    <param name="ios-package" value="CDVLocalStorage"/>
</feature>
<feature name="File">
    <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.file.FileUtils" />
</feature>
<feature name="FileTransfer">
    <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.filetransfer.FileTransfer" />
</feature>
<!-- Deprecated plugins element. REmove in 3.0 -->
<plugins>

</plugins>
```

I have in my Android manifest file the necessary permissions:

The following is my version of Cordova: 3.5.0-0.2.6

Everything works fine on iOS. On Android Logcat gives the following error:

"Uncaught ReferenceError: LocalFileSystem is not defined", source: file??android_asset/www/app.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was basically in the way plugins are being added. I find it really confusing the documents given on phonegap and cordova websites. I probably had to follow them both to make it work.
To add the necessary plugins info in plugins.xml you need to follow this:

http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.0.0/cordova_file_file.md.html#File

And for making changes to the config file you need to follow this:

http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.3.0/cordova_file_file.md.html#File

and then compile and run. I am not sure if there is any place where I can find a unified document. Please let me know if you know of any unified document which combines it all. I am using Phonegap 3.5 and cordova 3.5 version and looking at old documents to figure out a way

Answer (score 0):

You cannot mix up between iOS and android in the same config.xml file. Make sure you setup cordova plugin in separate config.xml

iOS

[image]

android

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However this is what was missing as posted on the answer above: It was basically in the way plugins are being added. I find it really confusing the documents given on phonegap and cordova websites. I probably had to follow them both to make it work. To add the necessary plugins info in plugins.xml you need to follow this:

http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.0.0/cordova_file_file.md.html#File

And for making changes to the config file you need to follow this:

http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.3.0/cordova_file_file.md.html#File

and then compile and run.